# Need to split a string using a delimiter and store its values in a Constructor (Java)

Tags: java, split, constructor

Song(String info): Initialize a Song by parsing a String that contains the title, artist, and time with a semicolon and a space used as the delimiter. For example, the info String for the song "Where the Streets Have No Name" by U2 is

`java "Where the Streets Have No Name; U2; 5:36"`

The time is given as a number of hours, minutes, and seconds separated by colons. The minutes and seconds are numbers between 0 and 59. If the song is less than an hour, only the minutes and seconds are given. Similarly, if the song is less than a minute, only the seconds are given.

Here is my code so far:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Song {
    
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private int[] time;
    private static final String INFO_DELIMITER = "; ";
    private static final String TIME_DELIMITER = ":";
    private static final int IDX_TITLE = 0;
    private static final int IDX_ARTIST = 1;
    private static final int TIME = 2;
    
    public Song(String title, String artist, int[] time) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.time = Arrays.copyOf(time, time.length);
    }
    public Song(String info) {
        String words[] = info.split(INFO_DELIMITER);
            this.title = words[0];
            this.artist = words[1];
            
            String temp = words[2];
            this.time = Arrays.copyOf(Integer.parseInt(words[2], Integer.parseInt(words[2].length)));
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
    
    public int[] getTime() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(time, time.length);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Within the public Song(String info) constructor, I don't know how to store the songs length into the int[] time ArrayList, so I was hoping one of you guys could help me out. For that constructor, we are parsing a single string that looks like this: (java "Where the Streets Have No Name; U2; 5:36"), we need to separate each value and store them in the class's variables.

Comment: I would change the duration to the total number of seconds, and store that. It's quick and easy to convert from seconds to whatever form you need it in.

Answer (score 0):

You should split the word containing time using `TIME_DELIMITER`.

If it is possible to use Java 8 Stream API, `time` can be set as follows:

```java
this.time = Arrays.stream(temp.split(TIME_DELIMITER))
                  .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                  .toArray();
```

or using old-style coding:

```java
String[] strTime = word[2].split(TIME_DELIMITER);
time = new int[strTime.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strTime.length; i++) {
    time[i] = Integer.parseInt(strTime[i]);
}
```